# Checking area of overlap between two dataframes with parallel dask GeoPandas

Tags: python, pandas, dask, geopandas, dask-dataframe

I have two different GeoDataFrames: One of which contain polygon squares in a large grid. The other contains larger, and fewer, polygons.
I wish to calculate the area of overlap within each of the grid squares with the other, larger squares.

To do so, I made a simple loop method

```
for _, patch in tqdm(layer.iterrows(), total=layer.shape[0], desc=name):
    # Index of intersecting squares
    idx = joined.intersects(patch.geometry)
    intersection_polygon = joined[idx].intersection(patch.geometry)
    area_of_intersection = intersection_polygon.area
    joined.loc[idx, "value"] += area_of_intersection
```

In an attempt to speed up this method, I converted the `layer` DataFrame, which contains the larger patches to a Dask-DataFrame.

I implemented it the following way:

```
def multi_area(patch, joined=None):
    # Index of intersecting squares
    idx = joined.intersects(patch.geometry)
    intersection_polygon = joined[idx].intersection(patch.geometry)
    area_of_intersection = intersection_polygon.area
    joined.loc[idx, "value"] += area_of_intersection
    return joined["value"]

layer_dask = dask_geopandas.from_geopandas(layer, npartitions=8)

with ProgressBar():
    joined["value"] = layer_dask.apply(multi_area, meta=joined, joined=joined, axis=1).compute(scheduler='multiprocessing')
```

This, however, returns the error  `AttributeError: 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'`, and at this point I am unsure if this is the optimal way of doing it, and what I am doing wrong.

The job I will be doing will have 400 million grid squares, so I am planning on batching this calculation out on smaller areas later, as I can't come up with a smarter way of doing it...

Comment: read the docs on geopandas spatial joins: https://geopandas.org/en/stable/gallery/spatial_joins.html. don't use intersection

Comment: Thanks, Michael. However, I still need to calculate the area of overlap between the grid and the patches. I'm guessing I can simplify this process now that the patches and grid are connected through a spatial join. But this is not completely clear to me. I would still need to run an "overlay", would I not? And then calculate the area from that. And that is also time consuming.

Comment: Does overlay do the trick? https://geopandas.org/en/stable/gallery/overlays.html

Comment: Well, ` gpd.overlay(df_grid, df_layer, how="intersection")` splits up the layer, with according to the underlying grid. But now I want to sum the area of the layers that intersect with each grid square and place that in the grid row.

I'm not sure how to do this in an efficient way. Spatial joins are highly optimised, but is overlay? I need to do this calculation for millions of grid squares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to speed up the process quite a bit using spatial joins and overlay as suggested by Michael in the comments.
In addition I implemented Dask Dataframes so the final code becomes:

```
import dask_geopandas as dg
import geopandas as gpd

def dissolve_shuffle(ddf, by=None, **kwargs):
    """Shuffle and map partition"""
    meta = ddf._meta.dissolve(by=by, as_index=False, **kwargs)

    shuffled = ddf.shuffle(
        by, npartitions=ddf.npartitions, shuffle="tasks", ignore_index=True
    )

    return shuffled.map_partitions(
        gpd.GeoDataFrame.dissolve, by=by, as_index=False, meta=meta, **kwargs
    )


def calculate_area_overlap_dask(
    df_grid,
    layer,
    nthreads=8,
) -> gpd.GeoDataFrame:
    """This function calculates the area of overlap in each grid cell for a given map-layer
    """

    layer = layer[["geometry"]]
    df_grid = df_grid[["geometry"]]

    # Split up the layer using the grid
    _overlay = gpd.overlay(layer, df_grid, how="intersection")
    
    # Convert the overlay to a dask geopandas dataframe and calculate the area of each new polygon
    _overlay = dg.from_geopandas(_overlay, npartitions=nthreads)
    _overlay["area"] = _overlay.area
    _overlay = _overlay.compute()
    
    # Convert the grid to a dask geopandas dataframe and spatial join all split layer polygons to corresponding grid cells
    df_grid = dg.from_geopandas(df_grid, npartitions=nthreads)
    joined = dg.sjoin(df_grid, _overlay, how="inner").reset_index()

    # Faster dissolve of area within each grid cell
    scored_grid = dissolve_shuffle(
        joined,
        "index",
    )
    scored_grid = scored_grid.compute()
    return scored_grid

def polygon_to_grid(name: str, gdf) -> gpd.GeoDataFrame:
    """This function converts a geodataframe to a grid of polygons
    """
  
    gdf["value"] = range(len(gdf.index))

    # Rasteriser polygonet
    out_grid: xr.Dataset = make_geocube(
        vector_data=gdf,
        measurements=["value"],
        resolution=(-100, 100),
        fill=np.nan,
    )

    vals: xr.DataArray = out_grid.value.values
    vals[~np.isnan(vals)] = np.arange(len(vals[~np.isnan(vals)]), dtype=np.int32)
    vals[np.isnan(vals)] = -9999
    out_grid.value.values = vals
    out_grid.rio.to_raster( f"{name}_raster.tif")
   
    # Read saved raster
    src: xr.Dataset = rasterio.open(f"{name}_raster.tif")
    r = src.read(1).astype(np.int32)

    # Convert polygons
    shapes = features.shapes(r, mask=r != -9999, transform= src.transform)
    polygons: list[Polygon] = list(shapes)
    geom: list[Polygon] = [shapely.geometry.shape(i[0]) for i in polygons]

    # Convert to geodataframe
    grid = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
        geometry=gpd.GeoSeries(
            geom,
        ),
    )
    return grid

if __name__=="__main__":
    area = gpd.read_file("some_area.shp")
    layer = gpd.read_file("some_map_layer.shp")
    area_grid = polygon_to_grid("area", area)
    grid_evaluated = calculate_area_overlap_dask(area_grid, layer)
```

This mess ended up working, but it was very prone to memory-issues with large datasets. So I opted for a solution that was less precise, but much faster.